# How to show a loading spinner when loading another aspx using asp.net and visual studio?

Tags: asp.net

I know this question has been asked many times, but I didn't seem to find any solution that I can understand online. Most says using javaScript and css but I don't really know how to implement that.

I'm using visual studio and i have a master page and several other content pages. On the master page I have a link that redirects me to one of these content pages using

"a href = pages.aspx"

Since the content page uses a SQL query to retrieve data so it takes a very long time. I would like to show a loading spinner or progress bar or even just a text saying "loading..." while the page loads.

Are there anyway to do this?

I also thought about using a label which is only visible when the link is clicked, and goes invisible when the page loads. Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried using updatePanel and updateProgress. I created a button inside updatePanel which directs me to the page. In the updateProgress I have a spinner gif. The redirecting works but the spinner gif doesnt show. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: add updatePanel and UpdateProgress on your content page

Answer (score 2):

An exact situation with detailed code and explanation, where a loading image is shown on loading of an asp.net page can be seen at following URL : [Show Loading Image when Page first Loads](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-loading-progress-image-when-Page-Loads-or-does-PostBack-using-ASPNet.aspx).

This has detailed explanation with full working code as well as a link to demo page. You can ask me if you have any questions regarding this sample.

To verify that the loading image shows up in above sample you can simply go to this URL : [Loading Image when Page first loads](http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/289/)

**Another very simple approach** with tested/tried sample code is as explained below.
You will need jquery in your aspx page for this to work.

There are three scenarios in which you would like to show a loader element in an aspx page and they are:

- On button click that does a non-ajax postback
- hyperlink click that navigates to another page
- on button click that does an ajax postback

*In first two of above scenarios*, all you need to do is hookup their client click event with a JavaScript method of `ShowProgress`. This method shows a popup div that has an animated image in it.

*In the last scenario* where an ajax postback is done, an `UpdateProgress` control is used so it automatically hides once the ajax postback completes.

The loader popup is styled to show at center of page in a modal manner'; these styles can be found in the `head` section of markup pasted below. You can modify some of these styles like `border` or `background-color` and also you can substitute any animated image in place of `loading.gif`.

*I tested the markup below with a Page `PageTakingLongToLoad.aspx` that took 20 s to load the first time it rendered, and with ajax/non-ajax postbacks that took 10 s to complete, and in both cases the loader displayed perfectly as expected.*

**Markup of Page from which a loader is shown**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InitialPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="InitialPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .modal {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: lightgray;
            z-index: 99;
            opacity: 0.8;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
            -moz-opacity: 0.8;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .loading {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            border: 5px dashed #f00;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: White;
            z-index: 999;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 35px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <div class="loading">
                <div>
                    Loading. Please wait.<br />
                    <br />
                    <img src="loading.gif" alt="loading" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="PageTakingLongToLoad.aspx" onclick="ShowProgress();">Link To Another Page </a>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPostBack" runat="server" OnClientClick="ShowProgress();" OnClick="btnPostBack_Click" Text="Do Long Process without Ajax" /><br /><br />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAjax" runat="server" OnClick="btnPostBack_Click" Text="Do Long Process with Ajax" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div class="loading" style="display: table">
                        <div>
                            Processing. Please wait...<br />
                            <br />
                            <img src="loading.gif" alt="loading" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             function ShowProgress() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var modal = $('<div />');
                    modal.addClass("modal");
                    $('body').append(modal);
                    var loading = $(".loading");
                    loading.css("vertical-align", "middle");
                    loading.css("display", "table-cell");
                    var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
                    var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
                    loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
                }, 200);
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I made it work by adding the updateProgress to right under the updatePanel. I don't know why it didn't work before. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: updatePanel will work for loading new pages provided you are making an ajax postback  when redirecting to a new page i.e. in the ajax postback code-behind you are redirecting to a new page.

Comment: @Michael, FYI -  I have added new code in my answer to show how you could show loader when a hyperlink is clicked to go to another page or when a button does a non-ajax postback.  So this would cover all cases you would like now or in future.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely take a look.